# JavaFx ComboBox customize dropdown menu

Tags: java, css, javafx

I want to customize the dropdown menu of a combo bar. Looking at the next image [image]

I would like to change the blue hover bar, the hovered text color, text font as well as default text font.

Thank you very much.

-UPDATED-

I only achieved this

```
   comboBox.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('" + ImageUtils.getPath() + "fieldTextBkg.png');"
            + "-fx-text-box-border: transparent;" 
            + "-fx-background-color: transparent, transparent, transparent, transparent;"
            + "-fx-text-alignment: center;");
```

that is only changing the unfolded menu. Whatever I am trying in order to modify the inner dropdown list, I am not possible to achieve. A start will be for example, the blue bar to be changed into Green. The whole background instead of white to be black, and text to be of font Calibri.

Thank you.

Comment: You do this with [CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#cell). [Edit] your question to describe how you want these to change, show what you have tried, and explain how the outcome is different to what you expect.

Comment: Sorry @James_D, updated it

Comment: You need to set the styles of the cells, not the combo box itself. You can only do that in an external style sheet (not with inline styles).

Comment: Can you post an example please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the style for the cells in the popup by placing the following in an external CSS file for your application:

```css
.combo-box .combo-box-popup .list-view, .combo-box .combo-box-popup .list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: black ;
    -fx-text-fill: white ;
    -fx-font-family: "Calibri" ;
}
.combo-box .combo-box-popup .list-cell:hover {
    -fx-text-fill: yellow ;
    -fx-background-color: green ;
}
```

You can use the pseudoclass `:selected` for the selected cell. (i.e. `.combo-box .combo-box-popup .list-cell:selected { ... }`).

You can style the combo box "button cell" (i.e the one that is displayed not in the popup) with the selector

```css
.combo-box > .list-cell { /* ... */ }
```

See the [CSS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#cell) or even the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) for the default stylesheet for more options.

Comment: Thank you very much. THIS IS WORKING!

Answer (score 9):

Here's a few explication :

```
 /*Edit The control itself*/
 .combo-box{

-fx-background-color:purple; 

 }

/*Edit Normal Cell color */
 .combo-box .list-cell{

-fx-background-color:red;


}

/*Edit Cell Color Only when cursor hover cell */
.combo-box .list-cell:hover{

-fx-background-color:green;
}

/*Edit Cell Color Only when selected */
.combo-box .list-cell:selected{

-fx-background-color:blue; 

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is perfect!

Comment: Actually James_D deserve it :)

Comment: I've looked up so many examples that don't work. This one works and it's all in CSS. Thanks!